what is a hyderation error in angular. or NG0500
<!-- home.component.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/swaroopvontela/my_portfs/src/app/home/home.component.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <img src="/Users/swaroopvontela/my_portfs/src/ironP.jpg" alt="Website Logo">
    <h1>Swaroop reddy vontela</h1>
</header>

<nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Home Page</h2>
    <p>web site under construction...</p>
    <p>looking for aws data engineer positions</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>

i am trying to create a web page. i guess i am using ssr(server side rendering) and ssg(static site generation) nothing fancy. i have a home component and the selector name is app-home. and when i do ng serve i am seeing the following error message in the console area. can you explain me why?
[Error] ERROR – Error: NG0500: During hydration Angular expected <html> but found <meta>.

Angular expected this DOM:

<app-home _nghost-ng-c2925092162="">
  <html lang="en">…</html>  <-- AT THIS LOCATION
  …
</app-home>

Actual DOM is:

<app-home _nghost-ng-c2925092162="">
  <meta _ngcontent-ng-c2925092162="" charset="UTF-8">…</meta>  <-- AT THIS LOCATION
  …
</app-home>

Note: attributes are only displayed to better represent the DOM but have no effect on hydration mismatches.

To fix this problem:
  * check the "_HomeComponent" component for hydration-related issues
  * check to see if your template has valid HTML structure
  * or skip hydration by adding the `ngSkipHydration` attribute to its host node in a template

 Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0500 — chunk-BF4XLKTU.js:3311
Error: NG0500: During hydration Angular expected <html> but found <meta>.


things tried:

i have checked the home component and did not find any issues
the template has a valid html syntax
how do i skip the hydration? what is a host node?


Your home component looks like a page. Components should be small pieces that can be added to a page.

okay got you...
